two different virtualhosts on apache2 but always redirected towards the first one
So we're trying to setup a test environment and run two different apps on 2 different PHP versions using apache2 to test possibility and whatnot before deploying to production, steps taken are :
1-setup 2 different virtualhost config files with disctinct servernames
2-disabling 000-default site on apache
3-a2ensite both conf files and using apache reload and restart (serviusfr and oldservius) both sites are present on the sites-enabled directory of apache2
this experiment is ran on an ubuntu VM version 20.0.4
issue that we're experiencing is that when we launch both apps and try to connect to them via local url (IP_ADDRESSE/SERVERNAME) we're always redirected to oldservius which is the legacy app running on php5.6.
below are the two virtualhost files configured for each app :
for serviusfr :
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      serviusfr
        ServerAlias     serviusfr
        ServerAdmin     adminweb@servius.fr
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/serviusfr
        DirectoryIndex  index.html index.php index.htm
        CustomLog       ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/serviusfr/access.log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
        ErrorLog        ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/serviusfr/error.log
        ErrorDocument   404 /error.html

        <IfModule mod_dav.c>
                DAVLockDB "/var/run/davlocks/.davlock100"
                DAVMinTimeout 600
        </IfModule>

        <Directory "/var/www/html/serviusfr">
                Options All -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes +MultiViews
                <IfModule mod_dav.c>
                        DAV Off
                </IfModule>
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        <FilesMatch .+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$>
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
        </FilesMatch>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

for oldservius (old app running php5.6)
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      oldservius
        ServerAlias     oldservius
        ServerAdmin     adminweb@servius.fr
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/oldservius
        DirectoryIndex  index.html index.php index.htm
        CustomLog       ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/oldserviusfr/access.log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
        ErrorLog        ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/oldserviusfr/error.log
        ErrorDocument   404 /error.html

        <IfModule mod_dav.c>
                DAVLockDB "/var/run/davlocks/.davlock100"
                DAVMinTimeout 600
        </IfModule>

        <Directory "/var/www/html/oldservius">
                Options All -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes +MultiViews
                <IfModule mod_dav.c>
                        DAV Off
                </IfModule>
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <FilesMatch /var/www/html/oldservius/.+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$>
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
        </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>

output of apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server oldservius (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/oldservius.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost oldservius (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/oldservius.conf:1)
                 alias oldservius
         port 80 namevhost serviusfr (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/serviusfr.conf:1)
                 alias serviusfr


i have tried everything i can think of/ find on forums but everytime i launch both apps and try to get to serviusfr i get automatically rerouted to oldservius
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
we have tried dissiting and ensiting and rewriting the conf files and verify the placements and everything else but to no avail.
